# PDO Class bindParam() not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to edit an INSERT query using bindParam().

Here is my code.

```
public function addProduct()
{
   $query = "INSTERT INTO producten (name, model, price, image, description) 
   VALUES (:name, :model, :price, :image, :description)";

   $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);


   $stmt->bindParam(":name", $_POST['name']);
   $stmt->bindParam(":model", $_POST['model']);
   $stmt->bindParam(":price", $_POST['price']);
   $stmt->bindParam(":image", $_FILES['file']['name']);
   $stmt->bindParam(":description", $_POST['description']);

    print_r($stmt);
}
```

$dbh object is created in the contruct function of the class;

```
public function __construct()
    {
       $user = "root";
       $pass = "";

       $this->dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projectname', $user, $pass);

    }
```

The $stmt->bindParam() returns true when tested but does not replace the given parameters.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this all the code? You don't execute the query :-?

Comment: Well it's not working so the code is not able to execute yet. I'm printing the $stmt to see if the query get's edited.

Comment: This may not be related, but "INSTERT" should be "INSERT" ;-)

Comment: It is , but thank you :)

Comment: Please do not edit your code and correct your mistake. Otherwise when we look at the code we see nothing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea about prepared statements is that you don't need to inject your raw parameters into the query to compose some SQL code with escaped data. Instead, you use simple place-holders and keep the data somewhere else. When the query needs to be run, you feed the database engine with both pieces of data (the SQL query with place-holders and the values that correspond to those place-holders) and the database itself takes care of the rest.

So:

1. PDO will not *edit* your query. It doesn't need to.
2. You still need to *run* the query. The "prepare" phase simply links a place holder with a variable, so the value can be read from the appropriate location when the query runs.
3. You can actually prepare once and run many times with different parameters.

*Note: some PDO drivers don't allow regular prepared statements (for instance, because the underlying DB engine does not fully support them). In that case, PDO will emulate prepared statements and actually perform good old escaping. But since PDO is an abstraction layer, this shouldn't change the way you deal with it.*

Comment: While being a good, informative answer, how does it relate to the question?

Comment: @Truth It answers it, see the last part of the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a typo (`INSTERT`). How to avoid it next time?

When constructing the PDO object, make sure `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` is `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, this will cause PDO to throw `PDOException`s upon errors. Do it as follows:

```
$this->dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projectname', $user, $pass, array(
                                                                                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                                                                               ));
```

Or using `PDO::setAttribute()`:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

---

What that does, is that it causes PDO (and PDOStatement) to throw a PDOException upon error. It will kill the script if unhandled, and can be handled in the following way:

```
try {
    $this->addProduct();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```